# IMAP search on header not working as expected

Tags: imap, exchange-server-2010, imaplib

I am building library for IMAP my search command works file for the Inbox folder it returns me a number which I can use to fetch the mail. However when I try to search on Sent Items it does not work it does not give an error but just returns Search OK without any numbers. Can you please point out why this behavior. I am hitting Exchange 2010.

My search command is something like:

```
search all HEADER Message-ID "<cc6aed80-955b-4800-a3ac-6c3942ceecac>"
```

This is exactly how it is described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302965

Answer (score 1):

Possibly of no use, but I ran into possibly the same problem.

In a mailbox with an email from "Bill Gates ", a search with the expression '(FROM "billy@microsoft.com")' returned nothing; a search for '(FROM gates)' return a hit.

I had to change my code to '(HEADER FROM "billy@microsoft.com")' to get it to work.

ALTERNATIVELY:
You may be able to use IMAP4.uid(command, arg[, ...])
See http://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.uid